# Moving points inside to polygon using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I have an address and building table in my PostgreSQL. There are some address points outside building polygons, the constrain is that all address must be inside of nearest polygon.

Is there a function that can help me?

Comment: do the addresses exist and match in both the address and building table?

Comment: if the addresses match on both the tables the query will be fairly simple. you would need to use the st_closestpoint function https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClosestPoint.html. if the addresses do no match on both tables you would first need to find the closest point to each polygon then use the st_closestpoint function